# Products in wishlist shared

Tags: magento2, email, wishlist, share-wishlist

I have an issue with the share wishlist emails in outlook (images are not rendered properly). I didn't find the table that renders items for the wishlist. Which exactly file displays the items, So I can add style to images. I can set template from admin but the code `{{var items|raw}}` coming from code, Need to find this.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **Check Below Files It's Helps you.**

```
<Magento Root>/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_share.xml

<Magento Root>/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_shared_index.xml
 
<Magento Root>/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_email_items.xml

<Magento Root>/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Share/Wishlist.php

<Magento Root>/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Share/Email/Items.php
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***